# how to setup php 8.3 with Apache on Loacl machine(in window 10)

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

gatting error

phpMyAdmin - Error
The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration. See our documentation for more information.

Open the php.ini file in a text editor.

Search for the line that contains extension=mysqli.

If the line is commented out (starts with a semicolon ;), remove the semicolon to uncomment it.

If the line is not present, you can add the following line to enable the mysqli extension:

ini
extension=mysqli